# Using JQuery AJAX to display a database in ASP

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic

As the title says I'm trying to use JQuery AJAX to display part of a database on an ASP site. Ive never used JQuery so I am kind of lost on even how to start. Any help for my problem or a point in the right direction towards a helpful tutorial site because a lot of the ones Ive been to so far are way above my head.

Answer (score 0):

beginner tutorial.
http://www.impressivewebs.com/jquery-tutorial-for-beginners/

The AJAX part is a little more complicated. 
What from the database are you trying to display?

Jquery is mainly an html querying language/helper, mainly for the client side. Helps to navigate the DOM.
The AJAX part is for connecting to functions or methods on the server side. And it can return various forms of data, from a simple string to blocks of html to json objects.

You would have to use AJAX to call a function, and the server function will query the database, and return what you need.

Comment: A friend of mine handed me so code and asked if I could change it. It is in asp and what I believe is VBscript and from what I can tell it takes the info from the database divides it up into two columns and displays relevant info on the page.